# Searching for a data structure which can act like a map as well as retrieve other information

Tags: c++, c

I have the following chars to whom I want to assign numbers consecutively if they are in the same bracket. E.g.

```
   [a,b],[c],[d,e],[f,g],[h]
   a=0, b=1,c=2,d=3,e=4,f=5,g=6,h=7
```

From the given char I want to retrieve the number which I can do with std::map in c++. However, once i assign these numbers with map. I loose the information that [a,b] are in one bracket and [c] is separate. This information I want to retain.

Is there some data structure which I can use such that: [a,b] can be assigned consecutive numbers and also I can get the information that [a,b] are in one bracket and [c] is the only ones in its bracket.

My approach was to use map...but it does not fit my need of later finding out whether [a,b] are in the same bracket. Can someone please suggest a data structure such that it satisfies my need of assigning numbers consecutively as well as retaining the information that they belong to the same bracket.

Comment: A `std::vector` of `std::map`? Or possibly the other way around?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I didnot get..can you please explain with an example

Comment: Like `std::vector<std::map<keytype, valuetype>>` or `std::map<keytype, std::vector<valuetype>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking, but this answer is based on my current interpretation.  Can't you just use a value type that stores the extra information about what group the char is in?  For example:

```
struct value_type
{
    int num;
    int group;
};
....
std::map<char, value_type> m;
m['a'].num   = 0;
m['a'].group = 0;
m['b'].num   = 1;
m['b'].group = 0;   // same group as 'a'
m['c'].num   = 2;
m['c'].group = 1;   // new group
// etc...

// testing if 'a' and 'b' are in the same group
if (m['a'].group == m['b'].group)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, there is no data structure that fits your needs perfectly (as far as I know). You can, however, easily design one yourself. Some suggestions:

- Map each character to a tuple or struct that contains the bracket number and the character number:

  ```
  struct CharData { int group; int characterNumber; };
  std::map<char, CharData> data;
  ```
- Use two containers: One contains a list of character groups / brackets, the other one is a plain map:

  ```
  std::vector<std::vector<char> > groups;  // Store groups in this container.
  std::map<char, int> mapping; // Store mapping to integers in this container.
  ```
- Use a vector of maps:

  ```
  std::vector<std::map<char, int> > data;
  ```

You can easily convert between these representations. They have different complexity for typical operations though. If it is important to you that you can check if a character is in a certain group and to access the number it is mapped to, then go four the first solution. If you need to list all characters of a group quite often or a character can be contained in multiple groups, then I would prefer the second approach. The last approach can be useful, if a character can be an element of multiple groups and you want to map it to different numbers depending on the group.